# How to make a fixed header with SlickNav

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, menu

I need to make a fixed header containing a slicknav menu.
This is the homepage of the JQuery plugin:  http://slicknav.com/

I know how to make a slicknav menu:   http://jsbin.com/UqUloNO/4

And i know how to make a basic fixed header:  http://jsbin.com/AwEDura/1/

But i don't know how can i put them together.
This is an example of what i am doing: http://jsbin.com/OzOgaFO/1/
There is the fixed header but the slicknav disappear under.

Someone knows how can i make a fixed header containing a slicknav menu?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just apply `position: fixed` style to your menu element. Example:

```
.slicknav_menu {
    display:block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

Working sample: http://jsbin.com/UqUloNO/2/